# Ingesting data from multiple streams with AWS Firehose / Data Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm designing a system that should be able to listen to over 1000 different event streams. Those are all HTTP streams, around 80% of the time the events are merely a heartbeat ( < 1Kb). The other 20% are actual events ( < 10Kb) and each event will trigger a different behavior.

It's important that the latency of the chain represented belowbe minimal, near real-time, but not necessarily so. To put into numbers a 5 to 10 seconds latency is perfectly fine for my purposes.

`Event occurred > event streamed > event ingested > event processed > behavior triggered`

*No long term storage needed*

I'm unsure what are the appropriate AWS services here, [AWS Kinesis Data Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/) or [AWS Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). I've never used any of them and I don't fully understand the actual difference between them.

**However Data Streams seems to be considerably more expensive than Firehose.**

1. From what I understand in **Data Streams** I'd need to pay `Per stream/per hour,` so 1000 streams * 24 hours * 30 days * price ($0.04) = 28.8k USD / month just to keep the streams running. That is added of +$0.08 per GB ingested. **Is that correct?**
2. While on **Firehose** I'm charged only on the data ingested, at an immensely lower rate: $0.029 per 500 TB / month

Admittedly I don't know how `Ingestion Direct PUT and KDS as a source` and `Ingestion Pricing for MSK as a source` actually work, so they may not fit my needs.

**ATM, I'm looking to understand if **AWS Firehose** can be used for my purposes, and if so, why **Data Streams** is so much more expensive?**

Comment: Firehose exists to aggregate streaming data, writing it to a destination (eg, S3) that wants a chunk of data rather than individual events.

Comment: Depending on ho you'll process the data, a single Kinesis Stream may be sufficient, as long as you provide some way to differentiate events. The architecture of such a system is out-of-scope for SO, but consider how you'll process the stream, and how much throughput you'll need (especially wrt readers, if you have multiple stream consumers).

Comment: Thanks @kdgregory! Does Firehose allow for me to filter from the stream what is written and what is not? If so, I might just filter the *heartbeats* and write only the event to RDS and then trigger the actions. (**Not sure if practical**). || Regarding using a single stream for **Kinesis Stream**, I assume I'd need to add a prior step that would aggregate all streams (from different devices) and funnel them into Kinesis. If that is the way, it feels like it would defeat the purpose of using Kinesis Stream, as the *aggregator* would be the bottleneck in scaling. Am I missing the point?

Comment: Well, first off, I don't believe that Firehose can write to RDS, so if that's your goal it's off the table to start. As for writing one stream or multiple streams, _something_ has to write to Kinesis. You mention "HTTP streams," which implies that you need something that listens for HTTP and writes to Kinesis, versus your devices writing directly. API Gateway can do this, as can (since you mention "devices") IoT Core. I don't know their scaling limitations offhand, but suspect that they're higher than you will need.

Comment: Bottom line is that you need to do some more reading and research, and try some proof-of-concept implementations.